# Repeat Method to Give "string" an "x" amounts of times

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that will take two arguments, one for the string, and the other the number of times it will be repeated. here is the code of i have:

```
 def repeat(text,c=2)
   c.times do print text end
 end

 repeat ("hi")
```

problem here is, I want to have the result to be "hi hi"
i tried "puts" but that starts a new line...
[    print text " + " text  ] doesn't work as well...

thanks for the help!

Comment: -1. Question is unclear. Repeating `"hi"` two times would give `"hihi"`, not `"hi hi"`.

Answer (score 28):

Your question is unclear.  If all you want is to print the text repeated n times, use [`String#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-2A)

```
def repeat(text, n=2)
  print text * n
end
```

Your example result says you want `"hi hi"` implying you would like spaces between each repetition. The most concise way to accomplish that is to use [`Array#*`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2A)

```
def repeat(text, n=2)
  print [text] * n * ' '
end
```

Comment: Boss. That's what you are.

Answer (score 20):

Simply multiply the string by the number, Ruby is smart enough to know what you mean ;)

```
pry(main)> "abcabcabc" * 3
=> "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc"
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you could do something like:

```
def repeat(text, c=2)
  print c.times.collect { text }.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 5):

`Enumerator#cycle` returns an enumerator:

```
puts ['hi'].cycle(3).to_a.join(' ')

# => hi hi hi
```

Breaking down the code:

`['hi']` creates an array containing a string

`cycle(3)` creates an enumerator from the array that repeats the elements 3 times

`.to_a` creates an array from the enumerator so that the `join` method of `Array` can create the final output string.

Comment: This is a very obscure way to say `['hi'] * 3 * ' '`

Answer (score 1):

I am new to ruby, but I thought this solution worked well for me and I came up with it myself.

```
def repeat(word, i=2)
  word + (" #{word}" * (i-1))   
end
```

Comment: def repeat(word, i=2); word*i; end

Comment: The only problem is see with your response is it would produce "wordword" if you fed it "word"  What we are looking for is "word word" with a space inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

```
def repeat(text, c=2)
  print Array.new(c, text).join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 def repeat(text, c=2)
   print ((text + ' ')*c).strip
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeat(text, c=2)
  print ([text]*c).join(' ')
end
```

Perhaps easier to read.  Unless, is there any reason to use the .collect method instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in creating an array (with or without collect()) and then calling join(). This works too:

```
def repeat(text, c=2)
  c.times { |i| print text; print ' ' unless i+1 == c }
end
```

Although, it is a little more verbose (which is arguably un-ruby like) it does less work (which maybe makes more sense).